# XML not well formed

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to build my android app and it is throwing the error:

```
Error:(1) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

I did some research on Stack and people had a similiar probelm when they mixed xml and java. After looking at the error it is throwing it for an .png file I am using which doesnt make much sense to me.

Here is a some more of the error showing:

```
Error:(1) Execution failed for task ':BeerPprtfolio:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/Mike/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/Mike/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar -M /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/beerportfoliov3/BeerPprtfolio/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/beerportfoliov3/BeerPprtfolio/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/beerportfoliov3/BeerPprtfolio/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/beerportfoliov3/BeerPprtfolio/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/beerportfoliov3/BeerPprtfolio/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/beerportfoliov3/BeerPprtfolio/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/beerportfoliov3/BeerPprtfolio/build/intermediates/res/debug/layout/ic_drawer.png:1: error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

Comment: would be really useful to see your xml code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Because adding `ic_drawer.png` image in `res/layout` folder but `res/layout` folder is used for placing layouts for screens in xml.

Move `ic_drawer.png` file in `drawable` folder.

Also in code and xml files make sure not getting `ic_drawer.png` as `R.layout.ic_drawer` because `ic_drawer` is image so use `R.drawable.ic_drawer` for getting id of `ic_drawer.png` in code or xml

Comment: I think you meant `R.drawable.ic_drawer` an not `R.id.ic_drawer`